# send udp socket multicast address in network framework iOS 17 version

Tags: ios, swift, network-connection, network.framework

I am trying send data multicast address via using NWConnectionGroup, I tried below code at iOS 15 version it works, it sends data and I received sended data, but When I try at iOS 17 version it connects successfully url and port, but it doesn't sending data, Why I can't send data from iOS 17 version, Can I need get specific permission?  meanwhile I tested  in simulator at iOS 17.2 version it sends data but real device can't send data.

```
func init() {
      var group: NWConnectionGroup!
      connect(withHost: "235.10.10.100", port: 3333)
    }

    func connect(withHost: NWEndpoint.Host, port: NWEndpoint.Port) {
        
        let multicast = try! NWMulticastGroup(for: [.hostPort(host: withHost, port: port)])
        group = NWConnectionGroup(with: multicast, using: .udp)

        group.setReceiveHandler(maximumMessageSize: 128) { message, data, b in
            print("Received message:")
        }
        group.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
            print("Group entered state \(String(describing: newState))")
        }
        group.start(queue: .global())
    }

func sendData() {
    let groupSendContent = Data("helloAll".utf8)
    self.group.send(content: groupSendContent) { error in (error)
        print("Send complete with error \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of [NWMulticastGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwmulticastgroup#) requires the [com.apple.developer.networking.multicast](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_networking_multicast) entitlement. There is a link for requesting it in the documentation.

I do not recommend just modifying the entitlement file by hand. It's tricky to do correctly. I recommend adding it in Signing & Capabilities. Add it through the "+ Capability" button:

[image: Multicast Networking Capability addition screen]

Note that you will need to have this entitlement on your provisioning profile. You need to request it from Apple using the link described above.

Comment: I added like below .entitlementf file, but not sending data                                                                                                             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.multicast</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: thanks for your replies, I am using Xcode 15.2 and I can't see Multicast Networking in Capability